# LaTeX Error: Please help me

Tags: errors

I'm getting the following error from my Latex code:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\&
l.27 ...ink{M\&A}{M\&A}]{Mergers and Acquisitions}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
)
\openout1 = `"BA.aux"'.
```

The Problem is the `\&` in (M&A) , but I don't know why.
Below is the LaTeX code for which I am getting the LaTeX error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, abstract, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\usepackage{listofsymbols}
\usepackage{booktabs} %Tabellen
\usepackage{tikz} %Timeline
\usepackage{caption} %Tabellenunterschriften
\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable} %Three Part Table
\usepackage{pgfplots} %Plot zeichnen
\usepackage{blindtext} %Bullets
\usepackage{enumitem} %Bullets
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry} %Seitenränder
\usepackage{acronym}  %Abkürzungsverzeichnis**



\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=25mm,
headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}
\linespread{1.3} % entspricht word 1,5 



%..............................................................................................................................................%
\pagenumbering{Roman} 
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
%..............................................................................................................................................%

%..............................................................................................................................................%
\setcounter{page}{2}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis\vspace{-10pt}}
\rule[0pt]{0mm}{10pt} %\rule[Offset]{Breite}{Höhe}
\newpage
%..............................................................................................................................................%
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tabellenverzeichnis\vspace{-10pt}}
\rule[0pt]{0mm}{10pt} %\rule[Offset]{Breite}{Höhe}
\newpage
%..............................................................................................................................................%

\section*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis} %Bitte alphabetisch ordnen!
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis\vspace{-10pt}}
\rule[0pt]{0mm}{10pt} %\rule[Offset]{Breite}{Höhe}
\begin{acronym}[Musterdingsbums]
\setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}
    % A
    \acro{NAFTA}{North American Free Trade Agreement}
    % B
    % C
    % D
    % E
    % F
    % G
    % H
    % I
    % J
    % K
    % L
    % M
    \acro{M\&A}{Mergers and Acquisitions}
    % N
    % O
    % P
    % Q
    % R
    \acro{ROE}{Return on Equity}
    % S
    % T
    % U
    % V
    % W
    % X
    % Y
    % Z
\end{acronym}

\newpage
\section*{Symbolverzeichnis} %Die hier verwendeten Symbole stellen eine beispielhafte Auswahl dar.
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Symbolverzeichnis\vspace{0pt}}
\rule[0pt]{0mm}{10pt} %\rule[Offset]{Breite}{Höhe}
\begin{acronym}[Musterdingsbums]
\setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}
    \acro{i}[$i$]{Interest rate}



\end{document}C
```

I'm using MacTeX (texmaker)

Thank You!

Comment: Hi, welcome. Note that your example currently is missing `\begin{document}` and  and `\end{acronym}` near the end, would be great if you could edit your question and fix that.